# OpenVPN Server on K3s Kubernetes Cluster: No Internet Access

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn, kubernetes, k3s

I've set up an OpenVPN server on a K3s Kubernetes cluster. While I can successfully deploy the OpenVPN server pod and connect from a client machine, the client doesn't have internet access through the VPN.

What I've tried so far:

- Added the following iptables rules:

  - `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
  - `iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`
  - `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT`
- Enabled IP forwarding:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```
- Verified the pod has internet connectivity
- Used the following `securityContext` in my deployment file:

  ```
  securityContext:
    privileged: true
    capabilities:
      add:
        - NET_ADMIN
  ```
- Enabled host networking:

  ```
  hostNetwork: true
  ```
- Specified the default OpenVPN port in my container config:

  ```
  ports:
    - name: vpn
      containerPort: 1194
      hostPort: 1194
      hostIP: 0.0.0.0
      protocol: UDP
  ```

I was able to get the OpenVPN server working when deploying it manually through Docker. I'm assuming that some K3s/Kubernetes networking rule is interfering with internet connectivity.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.